# show that the following integral converges if $s>n$?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I want to show that the integral

${\int\limits_{{\mathbb R^n}} {\left( {1 + \left| x \right|} \right)} ^{ - s}}dx$

is convergent if $s>n$

I am thinking to use the Fourier transform, but no idea how to start. Also, the integrand is radial, so maybe that will help.

I appreciate any tips.

Comment: Passing to polar coordinates, you get, up to a constant prefactor (exercise), $$\int_{0}^\infty (1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\,\mathbb dr.$$ Now split the integral up into an integral over $]0,1[$ and $]1,\infty[$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand how the split will helps. And this integral seems still complicated

Comment: The split is $$\int_{0}^\infty (1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\,\mathbb dr=\color{blue}{\int_{0}^1 (1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\,\mathbb dr}+\color{green}{\int_{1}^\infty (1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\,\mathbb dr}$$ For the blue term use $$(1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\le 1$$ and for the green term use $$(1+r)^{-s} r^{n-1}\le r^{n-s-1}.$$ (Note that all integrands are $\ge 0$.)

Comment: Your question also seems to be answered at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628343/convergence-of-int-1x-alpha-dx?noredirect=1) and [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687192/for-which-alpha-in-mathbbr-does-int-mathbbrn-big1x-big?noredirect=1).

Comment: Thanks for the help !